# Getting Error: No such file or directory from perror when using ifstream to load a file

Tags: c++

So I am working on an ascii rouge like thing and I was trying to implement a feature where the player could load different levels. When i run the code, it gives me this error: No such file or directory. The two files, SaveInfo.txt and the Level1.txt are both in the same folder as the program. Also in SaveInfo.txt, it says Level1, thats it. And in Level1.txt, it has a paragraph of random text with a total of 16 lines. NOTE: This is the cpp of a class called map. I have all the variables created in the .h file. I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I cout _levelNumber, it reads out Level1. So I have no idea why its not working.

This is where SaveInfo and Level1 are located: C:\Users\Knigh\Desktop\Code\Ascii Rougelike\Ascii Rougelike

```
#include "Map.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>


void Map::loadLevel() {
    ifstream load;
    load.open("SaveInfo.txt");
    if (load.fail()) {
        perror("SaveInfo.txt");
    }

    getline(load, _levelNumber);
    load.close();

    //Opens level file
    load.open(_levelNumber);
    if (load.fail()) {
        perror(_levelNumber.c_str());
    }
    load >> _levelSize; 
    for (int y = 0; y < _levelSize; y++) {

        getline(load, _levelLineBuffer);
        _level.push_back(_levelLineBuffer);
    }
    load.close();
}

void Map::printLevel() {
    for (int y = 1; y < _levelSize; y++) {
        cout << _level[y] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "The two files, SaveInfo.txt and the Level1.txt are both in the same folder as the program." - that's not necessarily where C++ loks for them - they need to be in the directory you run the program from, which if you are using an IDE is the project directory.

Comment: Can you please add the files tree of your program, including the places of SaveInfo.txt and the Level1.txt? One more thing, which IDE / OS do you use?

Comment: You are attempting to manipulate two files, `SaveInfo.txt` and `Level1.txt`. Write new functionality *in Isolation* as much as possible. Strip this code down to a version that reads `SaveInfo.txt` and does nothing else, and see if that works. Also, make another version that writes `Level1.txt` (using hard-coded values) and nothing else, and see if *that* works.

Comment: Neil: It is in the directory that i am running the program from. The IDE I am using is visual studio 2017.

KorelK: I will add that right now

Beta: I did this already, i had a level1.txt reader and it worked, same with SaveInfo. I get this error when I combine the two

Answer (score -1):

Solved: In the file called SaveInfo.txt, I forgot to write the .txt to the end of the first level file. So it did not recognize the file in the directory.